# Issue with torch.cuda() function

Tags: python, pytorch, cuda

I'm new to PyTorch. It is working when I use gpu running my program with TensorFlow. But this is a problem with PyTorch.
I search a lot, but cannot find any useful answer. Who can help me?

**Error:**
[image]
**My environment:**

- windows10 64bit
- python3.6
- cuda9.0
- cudnn64
- gpu:GTX965m

Comment: Don't post errors or code as images. they cannot be searched or cut and pasted for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see for yourself in the release notes [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.3.1), the PyTorch developers have decided to deprecate compute capability 3.0 and 5.0 devices from their builds starting with PyTorch 0.3.1.

Your device is a compute 5.0 device and is, therefore, not supported in the most recent versions of PyTorch.

You can read about what alternatives are open to you [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-no-longer-supports-this-gpu-because-it-is-too-old/13803) (basically use an older version of PyTorch, or build your own from source with support for your GPU).

Comment: I installed torch0.4.0. And I can use the gpu